# Small Program written in C

Tags: c

I'm new to programming in C and need help with my small assignment.

requirements of the C program:

1. to ask a user to type his username and password on the     command line input.
2. program should demand at least two user attempts  of     inputting the passwords. your program should     only terminate when the user has entered two identical     passwords.
3. program should store the username and password     pair into a text file called “user.dat” in the current     directory.

My Code seems to output to the file but i get this error  in the command prompt window:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache2 Aborted
```

I also need to put a loop in the code somewhere when
the passwords do not match to go back and prompt to re-
enter, at the moment my program just
prints "Your passwords do not match please re-enter
password i am not sure how to approach
it.

Below is what i have written :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char username [40];
  char pw [35];
  char confirmpw [35];

  FILE *fptr;

  fptr = fopen("user.dat", "w");

  // exiting program
  if (fptr == NULL) {
    printf("Error!");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("Please Enter Your Username:\n");
  fgets(username, sizeof(username), stdin);
  fprintf(fptr, "%s", username);

  printf("please Enter Your Password:\n");
  fgets(pw, sizeof(pw), stdin);

  // Confirm password prompt
  printf("please Re-Enter to Confirm Your Password\n");
  fgets(confirmpw, sizeof(confirmpw), stdin);

  if(strcmp(pw, confirmpw) == 0){
    fprintf(fptr, "%s", pw);
    fclose(fptr);
  } else {
    printf("Your passwords did not match please re-enter your password \n");
    //need some type of loop ?
  }

  fclose(fptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: double free means you deallocated some memory twice. Can you see which memory?

Comment: It's nice to see such a well formatted code in someone who is starting to learn C.  It's a very important thing  :)

Answer (score 3):

Put a while loop instead of an if statement to request for new password until the confirm password is correct.

And notice you closed the file two times in your code, once in the if statement and second time at the end of main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char username [40];
    char pw [35];
    char confirmpw [35];


    FILE *fptr;


    fptr = fopen("user.dat", "w");

    // exiting program
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }


    printf("Please Enter Your Username:\n");
    fgets(username, sizeof(username), stdin);
    fprintf(fptr, "%s", username);




    printf("please Enter Your Password:\n");
    fgets(pw, sizeof(pw), stdin);


    // Confirm password prompt

    printf("please Re-Enter to Confirm Your Password\n");
    fgets(confirmpw, sizeof(confirmpw), stdin);

    while(strcmp(pw, confirmpw) != 0)
    {
        printf("Your passwords did not match please re-enter your password \n");

        fgets(confirmpw, sizeof(confirmpw), stdin);
    }



    fprintf(fptr, "%s", pw);

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Programs that ask for a password usually ask again twice when passwords do not match.  I wouldn't trust very much myself if I typed the same thing twice wrongly so I would prefer the program to forget everything I typed.

Comment: i think you can also try this out a bit - maybe use a function to contain the reused `fgets` call

Comment: I don't want to influence much in your answer, but as he is learning, and it looks like he more or less knows what he's doing, I think it's better for his learning to let him write the actual code, and google for the solution with just a few clues. I would leave this answer as is, which is correct but could be improved. With that comment he should be able to do it better himself alone :)

Comment: @Cacahuete Frito Okay

Comment: I'll argue the counterpoint there.  A minimal working code example is invaluable compared to a google search keyword.  The OP already knows they need a loop.  That doesn't mean you have to complete the assignment for them either.  SO suffers right now from overly brief non-verifiable answers like "use a do/while loop!" and suffers even more - from questions without verifiable code - present question excluded .  "Execution or it didn't happen" is my mantra.

Comment: @DanielFarrell You got me.  I agree.  There are some cases where googling is painful, and examples are very bad.  I'll try to remedy that in the future :)

Answer (score 3):

let's start at the top.  When I try to compile your program as written, I see that you're missing an #include:

```
t.c:40:6: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'strcmp' with type 'int (const char *, const char *)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

To solve this I added

```
#include <string.h>
```

You should always expect your code to compile without any warnings.  Don't suppress or ignore them, just fix them.

Now let's talk about your loop.  My preferred way to loop until user input or other condition is met is with an infinite loop with a `break` inside a conditional.  The infinite loop `while(1)` might seem a bit weird, but if you try to move the conditional test into the `while()` expression, you'll see why I say it's more convenient to do it this way.

my demo program of the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char* expected = "12345\n";
  char entered[25];
  while(1) {
    printf("please Enter '12345': ");
    fgets(entered, sizeof(entered), stdin);
    if(strcmp(expected, entered) == 0){
      break;
    } else {
      printf("Incorrect input.  Please try again.  \n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

here it is in action:

```
$ gcc -o t2 t.c && ./t2
please Enter '12345': 12
Incorrect input.  Please try again.
please Enter '12345': 45
Incorrect input.  Please try again.
please Enter '12345': 12345
$
```

A final note: my comparison string contains `\n`. That's because the newline from the "enter" key when entering text at the terminal gets passed into the program.  That's not necessarily a problem for you because the newline is part of both strings to compare, but I did want to point out that the newline gets written into the destination file along with the rest of the password.

Comment: In regards to compiler warnings, I will take note of that in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

In case everything goes well, you are calling `fclose()` twice: the first one just after `fprintf()` and the second one just before `return 0;`.  You should only call it once, but I guess it was a simple error and you already knew that.  Internally `fclose()` may call `free()` which is why you are seeing that error.

As for your loop, I recommend using a `do { ... } while ();`.  Inside the while condition you should put the call to `strcmp()`.

Comment: fine suggestion but pretty light on the code examples

Comment: @DanielFarrell As he is learning, and it looks like he more or less knows what he's doing, I think it's better for his learning to let him write the actual code, and google for the solution with just a few clues. With this answer he should be able to do find out how to do it himself alone. Else, I'll be happy to be a bit more explicit :)

Comment: Thank you all for your help much appreciated